# Can imageView display live video? (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, camera

I have an app that can capture a photo, then set it to the iamgeView. now I want my app without capturing the photo, the `imageView.image` is the whole camera view, can iOS do this?

Comment: What you have done so far

Comment: I made a imageView, the image is photo I taken, just like my description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `UIImageView` cannot display the live camera feed. It sounds like you want to use an `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`. There are many examples of how to use it available for free on the Internet. Check out Apple’s own [AVCam sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010112-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) for one.

Comment: Thanks! This sample code will be a big help to me.
So if I want to DISPLAY a video not to use imageView, instead of using a UIView to preview a video.

Comment: But now can I capture the photo from view? like `imagePickerController`. The sample code use to save the photo, but I want to use it to imageview.